# Aging values in a queue: Best use of Windows timers?

Tags: windows, timer

I have an std::set that contains unique values.  I have an std::queue that holds the same values
in order to age the values in std::set.

I'd like to use a timer to determine when to pop a value from the queue and then erase the value from the set.
The timer is created/started every time data is added to an empty set/queue.
If data is added to a non-empty set/queue, no change is made to the timer.
The timer would fire every X milliseconds to execute a function.
The function would pop a value from the queue then erase that value from the set.
If the set/queue is now empty the timer would stop.
If the set/queue is not empty, no change is made to the timer.

This program runs in Windows 10.

Does this way make sense? Is there a better/more efficient/simpler way to age the data?

I've read the docs on Using Timer Queues so I see how the queue and the timers are created and destroyed.  What I don't see is a recommendation for starting/stopping timers.
Should I be creating a new TimerQueueTimer to wait for X milliseconds once, run the func and then create a new TimerQueueTimer if the set/queue is not empty?
Should I instead create a single TimerQueueTimer to run periodically X milliseconds but delete it once the set/queue is empty?

Is there a 3rd technique I should use instead?

Here's my example code.

```
using unsignedIntSet = std::set<std::uint32_t>;
using unsignedIntQ = std::queue<std::uint32_t>;
unsignedIntQ agingQ;
unsignedIntSet agingSet;

HANDLE gDoneEvent = NULL;
HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
HANDLE hTimerQueue = NULL;

VOID CALLBACK ageTimer(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{

    if (!agingQ.empty())
    {
        auto c = agingQ.front();
        agingSet.erase(c);
        agingQ.pop();

        if (!agingQ.empty())
        {
            // rerun CreateTimerQueueTimer() here?
        }
    }

    SetEvent(gDoneEvent);
}

int createTimerForAgingQ()
{
    // create timer if it doesn't already exist
    if (gDoneEvent == NULL)
    {
        gDoneEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        if (gDoneEvent == NULL)
        {
            std::cerr << "CreateEvent() error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
        if (hTimerQueue == NULL)
        {
            std::cerr << "CreateTimerQueue() error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer(&hTimer, hTimerQueue, (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)ageTimer, NULL, 500, 0, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
        {
            std::cerr << "CreateTimerQueueTimer() error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

void addUnique(unsigned char* buffer, int bufferLen)
{
    // hash value
    auto h = hash(buffer, bufferLen);

    // test insert into set
    auto setResult = agingSet.emplace(h);
    if (setResult.second)
    {
        // enqueue into historyQ
        agingQ.emplace(h);

        if (!gDoneEvent) createTimerForAgingQ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Research shows that the CreateTimerQueue/CreateTimerQueueTimer may not be the way to go.
[Use of ThreadpoolTimer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151230-00/?p=92741)